# pyspark udf with parameter

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions

Need to  transfer one pyspark dataframe colume `checkin_time` from milisec to timezone adjusted timestamp, timezone information is in another column `tz_info`.

Tried following:

```
def tz_adjust(x,tz_info):
    if tz_info:
        y = col(x)+ col(tz_info) 
        return from_unixtime(col(y)/1000)
    else:
        return from_unixtime(col(x)/1000)
    
def udf_tz_adjust(tz_info):
    return udf(lambda l: tz_adjust(l, tz_info))
```

While using this udf to the column

```
df.withColumn('checkin_time',udf_tz_adjust('time_zone')(col('checkin_time')))

got some error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'
```

Any idea to pass the second column as parameter to udf?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, what you are doing is a combination of UDF and partial function which could get tricky. I don't think you need to use UDF at all for your application purpose. You can do the following

```py
#not tested

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn('checkin_time', when(col("tz_info").isNotNull(), (from_unixtime(col('checkin_time')) + F.col("tz_info"))/1000).otherwise(from_unixtime(col("checkin_time"))/1000))
```

UDF has its own `serde` inefficiencies which is even worse when using with python as it puts an extra overhead of converting scala datatypes into python datatypes.

Comment: Yes, your solution is right. This is one solution I have already implemented. There are several other columns need same processing procedure so I think udf might be more scalable.